# How to keep selected value for every row item and update the products in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, buefy

I have a list of selected products and every row contains the name of the product and dropdown containing array of tags suggested for that product. User can select only one tag for every product and then update all changes together. Here is the code:

```html
<div class="columns" v-for="selectedProduct in selectedProducts">
  <p class="left"> {{selectedProduct.name}} </p>
  <b-dropdown aria-role="list">
    <button class="button is-primary" slot="trigger" slot-scope="{ active }">
      <span>Click me!</span>
      <b-icon :icon="active ? 'menu-up' : 'menu-down'"></b-icon>
    </button>

    <b-dropdownItem
      v-for="selectedProductTag in selectedProduct.tags"
      :key="selectedProductTag.id"
      @click=""
    >
      {{ selectedProductTag.name }}
    </b-dropdownItem>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

selected products look like this:

```
   // selectedProducts array
[
    // selectedProduct 1
    {
        id: 
        name: 
        tags: [{
            id: ...
            name: ...
        } {
            id: ...
            name: ...
        }]
    },

    // selectedProduct 2
    {
        id: 
        name: 
        tags: [{
            id: ...
            name: ...
        } {
            id: ...
            name: ...
        }]
    }
]
```

So the main question is how can I select one value from the selectedProduct.tags array and then modify the the main selectedProducts array by replacing the whole tags nested array with this selected single selectedProductTag value?

Update function where it should be passed:

```
async updateProducts (products) {
      const submitedProductData = products.map(product => ({
        product: {
          productName: productName,
          ...
          tag: 
})
}
```

Comment: Might help to see an example of your data/state before and after which you're suggesting.  Having a hard time understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Justin I've updated question with data structure also here is what is the goal. technically  the goal is  select one tag from the array for every product from their available tags and then update the original selectedProducts array by replacing those tags array with single selected tag value which will be selected from every drop down for every row.

Comment: I think you might want to instead have a second attribute that is whatever the user selected.  The naming of the attributes is sort of confusing because it implies that the user has already selected them "selectedProductTag", where as they actually represent the options to select.  If you replace the array with whatever it selected - what happens if the user changes their mind and wants to select something else?

Comment: @Justin You are right so how can I  pass selected tag id in the above updateProduct function? Later that function will be used with selectedproducts argument  also submitedProductData variable's value will be sent via api request

Comment: @Justin so the help is needed for handling click event correctly and also selected tag should be some how assigned inside method mentioned above for sending it later via api. Only one tagId can be sent per row (selected by user)